# Incremental compilation with TypeScript while using --noEmit?

Tags: typescript

I would like to use TypeScript's `--incremental` mode to make it faster on repeated runs. However my `tsconfig.json` sets `"noEmit": true` because I'm currently only using TypeScript for type checking and not code generation.

If I run `tsc --incremental --outDir ~/tmp/typescript --noEmit` it doesn't appear to output a `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file and therefore doesn't actually incrementally compile on repeated runs.

I suppose I could actually enable emit and run `tsc --incremental --outDir ~/tmp/typescript --noEmit false` but then it generates not just `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` but also a bunch of JS files I don't need, which isn't ideal.

Is there a way I can run `tsc --incremental --noEmit`, actually incrementally compile, and only generate the `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file needed for incremental compilation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: The combination of `incremental` and `noEmit` is finally possible with [TS 4.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#noemit-and-incremental).

---

Up to now, unfortunately there is no way to have `incremental` builds with `noEmit` option enabled for faster type checking runs. E.g. this would be useful, when there is a separate typescript compile step with `@babel/preset-typescript` or similar.

Developer's statement regarding your question:

> The problem here is that incremental is on by default if composite is on, so this is an actual risky change because it's going to mean new build artifacts in unexpected places for people using --noEmit today.
>
> If the build info file path is specified manually, then writing it out does seem OK

So hopefully there is a chance, that such a feature will be implemented in future releases. You may follow [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30661) for progress tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the research and the helpful link!

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#build-and-noemitonerror @DavidFoster

Comment: Based on the link above, TypeScript 4.0 now allows --incremental with --noEmit.

Comment: @DavidFoster yeah, this combination is finally possible and good news for TS 4.0 users! For older TS versions, there is a workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563961/option-noemit-cannot-be-specified-with-option-incremental/62622318#62622318) in the meanwhile. Thanks for notifying