# Option 'noEmit' cannot be specified with option 'incremental'

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, next.js

I am developing a next.js app. It has the following `tsconfig.js`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018",
      "es2019.array"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "server",
    "next.config.js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "lib/global.d.ts",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

It is running well in the development mode but while creating build it shows following error:

```
ERROR in tsconfig.json
22:5 Option 'noEmit' cannot be specified with option 'incremental'.
    20 |     "resolveJsonModule": true,
    21 |     "isolatedModules": true,
  > 22 |     "noEmit": true,
       |     ^
    23 |     "incremental": true
    24 |   },
    25 |   "exclude": [
```

**Next.js** automatically injects *'noEmit: true'* in `tsconfig.json` file. While i really need the incremental mode for faster builds. What can be the solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

### TS 4.0+

`--incremental` with `--noEmit` [is possible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#noemit-and-incremental) now:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "noEmit": true,
  "incremental": true,
  // "tsBuildInfoFile": "/tmp/my-proj/tsbuildinfo" // custom build info file path
  // ...
}
```

The build info file [is emitted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39122) even with `noEmit`. You can set its explicit location via [`--tsBuildInfoFile`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Otherwise `outDir` - if still set - or `tsconfig.json` project root is taken as emit directory.

### Older versions (workaround)

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true, // to emit at least something
    // "noEmit": true,
    // ...
    
    // Either set overall output directory
    "outDir": "dist",
    //  or separate locations for build file and declarations 
    // "declarationDir": "dist"
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "/tmp/my-proj/tsbuildinfo"
  }
```

### More info

- [Allow noEmit and composite together in 3.7 #33809](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33809)
- [.tsbuildinfo file should be created when the noEmit flag is enabled #30661](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30661)

Answer (score 3):

From [TypeScript issue #33809](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33809#issuecomment-589446027):

> It really doesn't make sense to have `incremental` and `noEmit` together, since `noEmit` prevents us from writing incremental metadata. (So nothing is actually incremental).
>
> You should consider `emitDeclarationOnly` instead of `noEmit`, if you actually just want incremental checking.

According to this, the `incremental: true` flag has done nothing to speed up the build while `noEmit: true` is defined. So you should either remove `noEmit: true` or change it to `emitDeclarationOnly: true`.

You can control the output folders using `outDir` and `declarationDir`.